# Custom validation before create in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a before_create function which i am using to populate a column in the table . For instance
     before_create :generate_number

```
  def generate_number 

   end
```

I want to check the uniqueness of the column before its populated based on a condition .

example : if the number is created in database 2years ago i dont want the uniqueness validation to be applied on it

how could i write a custom validation for it. And where i should include it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unless` or `if` to apply logic to a validation:

```
validate_uniqueness_of :column_name, unless: -> { created_at < 2.years.ago }
```

This would go in your ActiveRecord model in the same manner as your `before_create`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...

  validate_uniqueness_of :column_name, unless: -> { created_at < 2.years.ago }
end
```

Comment: In this case would it leave the name blank if it doesnt satisy the validation?

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified in a comment that you'd like for it to continue generating numbers until one is generated that is not already in the database:

```
def generate_number
  begin
    value = generate
  end while created_at < 2.years.ago && Table.exists?(column: value)
  self.column = value
end

def generate
  ... # Code to generate number here
end
```

This continues looping `while` the created_at column is sooner than 2 years ago and the number generated is in the database. I put the `while` conditional at the bottom so that `generate` will run at least once before being checked.

I still don't understand the purpose of the created_at conditional, I can modify that part if you would like to specify how it should work. Otherwise, I'll just consider it an example, and not part of the actual issue.

Comment: yes i would want to prevent it from creating and call the random function again so that a diffrent number is generated if the validation doesnt satisfy

Comment: Alright, I've updated the answer to include a loop to continue generating until it creates a number that is not already in the database.